# Using Smith normal form to find basis of $K=\langle (2,4,1),(1,3,2),(1,1,1)\rangle\subset\Bbb Z^{(3)}$. Is the decomposition unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

> Let $K$ be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z^{(3)}$ generated by the three vectors $(2,4,1),(1,3,2),(1,1,1)$
>
> Find a basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ of $\Bbb Z^{(3)}~$ and integers $d_i,~1\le i\le r$ such that $d_i\mid d_{i+1}~\forall 1\le i\le r-1$ and $(d_1e_1,\dots,d_re_r)$ forms a basis of $K$. Determine the invariant factors of the group $\Bbb Z^{(3)}/K$.

There is an algorithm for finding matrices $R, S$ with $\det=\pm1$ such that $RAS=D$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with invariant factors of $\Bbb Z^{(3)}/K$ in the diagonal.

Let $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 &1 &1\\
4 &3 &1\\
1 &2 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ be the matrix that satisfies $\langle Ax~:~x\in\Bbb Z^{(3)}\rangle =K$

I found $RAS=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&0&1\\
1&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 &1\\
4 &3 &1\\
1 &2 &1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&1&1\\
1&-1&-3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4
\end{pmatrix}=D$

Now since multiplying $A$ on the right by $S$ preserves the span (permutes columns), $$ \operatorname{span}(A)= \operatorname{span}(AS)= \operatorname{span}(R^{-1}D)$$ and that's how we get that the columns of $R^{-1}$, call them $e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix},e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$
multiplied by each of the invariant factors respectively $d_1=1,d_2=1,d_3=4$ generate $K$.

$$K=\langle d_1e_1,d_2e_2,d_3e_3\rangle$$

Now I thought that $R$ and $S$ are unique but apparently the following decomposition works as well:$$\begin{pmatrix}4&-2&1\\-2&1&0\\5&-3&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\4&3&1\\1&2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-3\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4
\end{pmatrix}$$

How is this possible?

Wolfram alpha so you don't have to verify:

[one way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B-1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,-2%7D%7D*%7B%7B2,1,1%7D,%7B4,3,1%7D,%7B1,2,1%7D%7D*%7B%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,1,1%7D,%7B1,-1,-3%7D%7D) [other way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(inverse%20of%20%7B%7B2,1,-1%7D,%7B4,3,-2%7D,%7B1,2,0%7D%7D)*%7B%7B2,1,1%7D,%7B4,3,1%7D,%7B1,2,1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1,0,-3%7D,%7B0,1,1%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D)

Comment: $R$ and $S$ are not unique. For example, if $A$ is the identity, then we can replace $R$ by $RX$ and $S$ by $X^{-1}S$ for any unimodular matrix $X$.